# How to keep Side Bar from scrolling with the page when minimized. CSS fix?

Tags: web, responsive-design

I've made a sidebar but it scrolls with the page when minimized. Is there a way to keep it in place when scrolling using CSS? I'm sorry if I formatted this question oddly, I'm very new here. I've added an image that hopefully helps.[side bar follows to where ever scrolled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWVO6.png)

I tried to follow a tutorial when I added the side bar but I don't think it factored in that there's a header as well.